# Parse Anonymous Utils: How to only create one user?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a quick question. I'm trying to enable automatic user creation in my app, so that when you open it for the first time, one and only one user is created. I read the User docs thoroughly, and found that Parse persists the user session on disk, and that once you save an object to that user, that user is saved on the cloud. However, I've noticed two problems with this:

1) When I save an object and create a pointer to the Owner User, the user object does not exist on the cloud.

2) If I check whether the current user is linked using ParseAnonUtils.isLinked(), this sometimes returns true, as in the current user is linked, or false, as in the current user is not linked, for the same exact ParseUser that was cached on session.

Here is the method I'm using to create and determine the user:

```
private void getUser() {
    if (!ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
        Log.v("Miles", "new user");
        ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                  user.setUsername(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                  user.setPassword(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                  user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        Log.v("Miles", "user saved");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.v("Miles", "user not saved " + String.valueOf(e.getCode()));
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                        } else {
                            Log.v("Miles", "signup fail " + String.valueOf(e.getCode()));
                        }
                    }
                  });
                } else {
                    Log.v("Miles", "anon login fail " + String.valueOf(e.getCode()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.